# Size of the stack for value types

Tags: .net, value-type, stack-size, stack-memory

All say that value types are stored on the stack. But **what is the size of the stack where value types are stored**? Nobody explains about it.

Comment: Value types are not always stored on the stack. In fact, a lot of the time they are embedded into object instances that are stored on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

It is the job of the jitter to calculate the size of the stack frame for a method.  That's a pretty straight-forward addition of the sum of the sizes of all the local variables in the method.  All the small value types take 4 bytes, long and double take 8, decimal takes 16, struct takes the summed size of its aligned members.  Reference type references take 4 bytes in 32-bit mode, 8 bytes in 64-bit mode.

Further refinement is that the jitter optimizer can move local variables into CPU registers, speeding up the code and reducing the required stack frame storage if it doesn't have to be spilled.

The sum of the sizes of the stack frames for nested method calls, plus the overhead of saved cpu registers, return address and method arguments cannot exceed the allocated size of the stack.  By default one megabyte for 32-bit code, four megabytes for code compiled with x64 as the target.  Or the *maxStackSize* argument of the Thread class constructor.  Exceeding the allocated size produces the fatal exception this site is named for.

Actual outcome depends a great deal on the jitter being used, x86 vs x64 vs ARM.  And whether the Debug or the Release build is used.  You should thus consider this a complete implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

The stack size is configurable and [can be set in several different ways](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx).

[By default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774.aspx) it is set to `1 MB`. For the ASP.NET apps, it is `256 KB` ([more information here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932909/en-us?fr=1)).